# Do sounding rockets need a license to be launched?

Tags: nasa, isro, esa, sounding-rocket, faa

I am just curious to know if any kind of license is needed to launch a sounding rocket? If yes, then what kind of licenses are there for sounding rocket launches.

Comment: The country-agnostic answer would be: 1) Permission to use the airspace of your country. 2) Permission to handle explosive materials.

Comment: And permission to use radios of the range you'll need.  And satisfy the authorities about the safety of anything that comes off the rocket (inevitable unless you have single-stage-to-orbit, something I do not believe has been done.)